# XRM JavaScript - if user selects themselves, throw an error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I am trying to introduce client-side scripting which prevents a user in my model-driven app from selecting themselves in a Lookup field which looks up to the AAD User table. However, this isn't having the desired effect and the user can still select themselves. Can anyone suggest why?

Here is my current JS using Xrm.WebApi...

```js
function preventSelfSelection(executionContext) {
  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
  // Retrieve the current user ID without curly braces
  var userId = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings.userId.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
  console.log("Current User ID: ", userId);

  // Retrieve AAD ObjectId of the current user via Web API
  Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("systemuser", userId, "?$select=azureactivedirectoryobjectid").then(
    function success(result) {
      var currentAADObjectId = result.azureactivedirectoryobjectid;
      console.log("Current User AAD ObjectId: ", currentAADObjectId);

      // Get the AAD ObjectId from the "digphil_peerreviewer" field
      var peerreviewer = formContext.getAttribute("digphil_peerreviewer").getValue();
      if (peerreviewer && peerreviewer.length > 0) {
        // Retrieve the selected user ID without curly braces
        var selectedUserId = peerreviewer[0].id.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
        console.log("Selected User ID: ", selectedUserId);

        // Get AAD ObjectId of the selected user
        Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("systemuser", selectedUserId, "?$select=azureactivedirectoryobjectid").then(
          function success(peerreviewerResult) {
            var selectedAADObjectId = peerreviewerResult.azureactivedirectoryobjectid;
            console.log("Selected User AAD ObjectId: ", selectedAADObjectId);

            if (currentAADObjectId.toLowerCase() === selectedAADObjectId.toLowerCase()) {
              formContext.getControl("digphil_peerreviewer").setNotification("You cannot select yourself", "self_selection_error");
              formContext.getAttribute("digphil_peerreviewer").setValue(null);
              console.log("User attempted to select themselves. Resetting field.");
            } else {
              formContext.getControl("digphil_peerreviewer").clearNotification("self_selection_error");
            }
          },
          function(error) {
            console.log("Error fetching selected user AAD ObjectId: ", error.message);
            // Handle error
          }
        );
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("Error fetching current user AAD ObjectId: ", error.message);
      // Handle error
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Did you consider setting a lookup filter instead? See [MS Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/controls/addcustomfilter).

Comment: if the lookup digphil_peerreviewer points to AADUser table, the ID is already the azureactivedirectoryobjectid, so you don't need to retrieve again the a systemuser record (that also may not exists), so in the end you need to compare currentAADObjectId  and selectedUserId

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this a lot easier

- `Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings.userId` returns the ID of the current user record
- `formContext.getAttribute("digphil_peerreviewer").getValue()` gets the ID of the currently selected user record from the lookup

If these values are the same, then the current user has selected their own user record. You don't need to do a `Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord` or anything complicated like that.

try something like this

```
function preventSelfSelection(executionContext) {
  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

  // Retrieve the current user ID without curly braces
  var userId = Xrm.Utility.getGlobalContext().userSettings.userId.replace(/[{}]/g, '').toLowerCase();
  console.log('Current User ID: ', userId);

  var selectedUserId = '';
  var peerreviewer = formContext.getAttribute('digphil_peerreviewer').getValue();
  if (peerreviewer && peerreviewer.length > 0) {
    // Retrieve the selected user ID without curly braces
    selectedUserId = peerreviewer[0].id.replace(/[{}]/g, '').toLowerCase();
    console.log('Selected User ID: ', selectedUserId);
  }

  if (userId === selectedUserId) {
    formContext.getAttribute('digphil_peerreviewer').setValue(null);
    formContext.getControl('digphil_peerreviewer').setNotification('You cannot select yourself', 'self_selection_error');
    console.log('User attempted to select themselves. Resetting field.');
  } else {
    formContext.getControl('digphil_peerreviewer').clearNotification('self_selection_error');
  }
}
```